# How to log non fatal errors in the console while running a http4s server in Scala

Tags: scala, error-handling, logback, internal-server-error, http4s

I have been using http4s for a while now. However, every time I am handling runtime errors, my workflow is very slowed down due to, for example, when I make a request to an endpoint and something goes wrong (either the JSON in the body cannot be encoded correctly by Circe, the request to the database was not successful, etc.), the response from the server is a generic 500 error and nothing appears in the console.

However, when testing the piece of code that I think is giving errors without resorting to the http4s API, I do get the corresponding error in the console.

So my question is, is there any way to show this kind of errors in the console at the moment they occur, for example, through some logback frontend configuration, or an IDE setting? This is mainly so that I can identify exactly what error is, and in which part of the code this error is appearing, so I don't have to debug everything that is happening internally at the time of making the request to the endpoint.

I really hope that something like this is possible. And if not, how do you handle this kind of situations when creating servers using http4s?  I would be very grateful for your advice.

Thanks and, have a nice day!